# Find container item index linkbutton in datalist?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datalist, linkbutton

I have two DataList control.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList0" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="staticid" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>'>
         </asp:Label>
        <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Players") %>'
            OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate> 
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="linkbutton" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Order") %>' 
                     runat="server"> 
                    <%# Eval("Name") %>
                 </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Here is my ItemDataBound event:

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
        LinkButton btn= (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("linkbutton");
        if (btn.CommandArgument.ToString() == "13")
        {
            //find btn container itemindex value.

        }
}
```

I want to find `btn` container item index value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You find index of datalist item like this:

```
if (btn.CommandArgument.ToString() == "13")
{
    //find btn container itemindex value.
    int ItemIndexValue = e.Item.ItemIndex;
}
```